# Is the Rāma Lalla murti that's up for consecration designed in accordance with the shāstras?

Tags: scripture, rama, temple, idols

**Jai Sri Rama**

As you all are aware about the recent consecration of Rāma Lalla's idol in the newly constructed Ayodhya temple.
At first when a quick glance of the idol was [revealed](https://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/etimes/trending/photos-first-look-of-the-mesmerising-idol-of-ram-lalla-revealed/articleshow/106991571.cms), people were not happy about the "reveal" before the consecration of course but, there were a group of people in Twitter as well who objected to the type of stone used, missing janeu, etc.

My question is

1. Is the murti design really violating any shāstra?
2. Are there really any scriptures like vastushastra that suggest how the idols are supposed to be designed accordingly?

Comment: In my opinion, there are no *serious* violations of anything. But, there is always the scope of doing few things better.

Comment: Vishnu idols/temples for worship have to follow vaikhanasa/pancharatra samhitas or puranas (vishnudharmottara, agni, matsya, etc.). Some violations are inevitable as modern day sculptors are not aware of these texts and people well versed in these these texts may not be sculptors. Experts and sculptors should be working together to build the right idol which doesn't happen these days.

Comment: If you could elaborate the comment to an answer at below then I'm sure that'd qualify as good justification and would be great of you of course. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Are there really any scriptures like vastushastra that suggest how the idols are supposed to be designed accordingly?**

According to **mahAbhArata ashvamedhikaparva ch. 104** (southern recesion), vishnu idol worship have to follow **vaikhanasa (purusha, satya, achyuta, aniruddha)** OR
**pancharatra (vasudeva, pradyumna, sankarshana, aniruddha)** :

> *yudhiShThira uvAcha*
> *kathaM tvamarchanIyosi ****mUrtayaH**** kIdR^ishAstu te. ****vaikhAnasAH**** kathaM bruyUH kathaM vA ****pA~ncharAtrikAH****.. 14-104-83*
>
> *bhagavAnuvAcha*
> *shR^iNu pANDava tatsarvamarchanAkramamAtmanaH. sthaNDile padmakaM kR^itvA chAShTapatraM sakarNikam.. 14-104-84*
>
> *aShTAkSharavidhAnena hyathavA dvAdashAkSharaiH. vaidikairatha mantraishcha mama sUktena vA punaH.. 14-104-85*
>
> *sthApitaM mAM tatastasminnaryayitvA vichakShaNaH. ****puruShaM**** cha tataH ****satyamacyutaM**** cha yudhiShThira.. 14-104-86*
>
> ****aniruddhaM**** cha mAM prAhur****vaikhAnasa****vido janAH. anye tvevaM vijAnanti mAM rAjan****pA~ncharAtrikAH****. 14-104-87
>
> ****vAsudevaM**** cha rAjendra ****saMkarShaNama****thApi vA. ****pradyumnaM**** ch ****AniruddhaM**** cha chaturmUrtiM prachakShate.. 14-104-88

Above chapter is missing in KMG english translation available online however gita press hindi translation includes above chapter [here](https://archive.org/details/mahabharata-Volume6/page/n2151/mode/1up)

Answer (score 1):

Agni Puran 49.6
rāmaścāpī śarī khaḍgī śaṅkhī vā dvibhūjaḥ smṛtaḥ |
gadālāngaladhārī ca rāmo vātha caturbhujaḥ || 6 ||
(The figure of) Rama should have the bow, arrow, sword, conch or two hands or may have four arms holding a mace and. plough.
Translation by N. Gangadharan 1954

You can check Chapter 44 of Agni puran for dimensions of idol of Bhagwān Narāyana/Vāsudeva.

Don't sure about the type of rock because Krishna shila is used in Sri rama lalla's idol and may be similar rock is used in idols of Sri Kodandaramaswamy Temple, and issue regarding Yajnopavit, idol is 5 years old,Yajnopavit ceremony or upnayan took place after 6-8 years

Comment: "Rama should have the bow, arrow, sword, conch or two hands or may have four arms holding a mace and. plough." Does that hold applicable in his 5 year old child Bālroop as well?

Comment: These are the symbols to differentiate the idols of different forms of Bhagwān Narāyana in the same chapter of Agni Puran I.e. 49 Other symbols are given for different avatars of Bhagwān Narāyana, There is not any minimum age given for holding the Dhanush or Ban.(That mace and plough idol is of [Bal] Rāma as per my understanding, this shloka clubs both Rāma Avatar)